# Codeigniter form not being submit

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

i am creating a website contact form. This is my code

```
<?=
form_open(site_url('contactus'), array(
    "id" => "contact_form",
    "class" => "form-horizontal",
    "name" => 'contact_form',
    "role" => 'form',
    'autocomplete' => 'off'
))
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input class="form-control" required="required" type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" size="40" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Your name here">

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input class="form-control" required="required" type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" size="40" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Your email">

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input class="form-control" required="required" type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="" size="40" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Subject">

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input class="form-control" required="required" type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="" size="40" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Phone">

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <textarea class="form-control" required="required" name="message" id="message" cols="40" rows="4" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE">
    </div>
</div>
<?= form_close() ?>
```

When I click Submit, the form is not submitted. Any idea why?

**EDIT: This is my rendered form**

```
<form action="http://localhost/omanpost/contactus" id="contact_form" class="form-horizontal" name="contact_form" role="form" autocomplete="off" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input name="jaisud98374yihfi928hf" value="6a0eb5820d293015b087fecc73986dec" style="display:none;" type="hidden">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input class="form-control" required="required" name="name" id="name" value="" size="40" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Your name here" type="text">

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input class="form-control" required="required" name="email" id="email" value="" size="40" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Your email" type="email">

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input class="form-control" required="required" name="subject" id="subject" value="" size="40" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Subject" type="text">

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input class="form-control" required="required" name="phone" id="phone" value="" size="40" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Phone" type="text">

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <textarea class="form-control" required="required" name="message" id="message" cols="40" rows="4" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" id="contact_button" value="SEND MESSAGE" type="submit">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: how the `<form>` tag is rendered? Can you check with your browser console if there is any request sent, console error or whatever? Maybe some js plugin is manipulating the form?

Comment: It is rendered as <form action="http://localhost/omanpost/front/contactus" id="contact-form" class="form-horizontal" name="contact-form" role="form" autocomplete="off" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

Comment: the `action` looks like a relative URI, put `http://` in front of it

Comment: @fustaki there is already a http:// in url. It got changed into the link when I pasted it.

Comment: You are also not posting to a controller by the looks of it. looks like you want /contactus for the contactus controller

Comment: The form is not even being submitted. When I click submit, nothing happens

Comment: first of all check if the `POST` request is actually sent by the browser, using the console

Comment: Can you try using base_url() instead of site_url()?

Comment: You should paste the generated form somewhere and link here...

Comment: if there isn't any network activity when you click on submit... could be some browser restriction with `localhost`: try with method `GET`, try with another browser

Comment: @fustaki I updated my rendered form too

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: None. Nothing is being happening.

Comment: Ok, I guess I found the answer. Your submit button is missing name tag.

Comment: @Rahi still nothing

Comment: I copied and pasted the above form on a blank page and submit button does work. I wonder if some JS code is conflicting. Can you change attribute names and strip off bootstrap classes and then try?

Comment: I think I might use ajax. :(

Comment: @AliZia is this solved ?